# How is a dual-pivot caliper brake capable of providing more braking force than a single pivot?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Bicycle rim caliper brakes come in two styles, **single-pivot** and **dual-pivot**

[image]
[image]

 There's one pivot bolt (the fulcrum) at the top, so this is a pair of class 1 levers in opposition to each other.

Compare that with a dual pivot design which is more complex.

[image]
[image]

That's a mess.  The difference is there is a new part in the back (magenta), which pivots around the center bolt and provides a pivot point for the front leg (red)  The two pivots are marked in green.

Subjectively in use, a Dual Pivot generates more braking by squeezing harder for the same finger input - or **increased mechanical advantage**

The main arms (red and yellow) are still class 1 levers in opposition, but what is the magenta arm?   Is it not a lever at all and the extra mechanical advantage comes from relocating the fulcrum/pivot some ?

Comment: This question might be better posed to [engineering.se]

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine yeah Physics.SE has over 700 results searching for "lever" and engineering is under 300 results so I guessed here was better.  I'm totally open to migrating though

Comment: I believe this article will answer your question: https://brainybiker.com/dual-pivot-vs-single-pivot-brakes-comparison-analysis/